# Back button always backs to the main activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 3 activities:

MapActivity
ScheduleActivity
ItemDetailActivity

MapActivity and ScheduleActivity can start ItemDetailActivity.
The problem is when I click in the back button, it always backs to the MapActivity. I've been searching in this forum, a lot of people answer "override the onBackPressed and start the intent".
I've tried many things, like: override the onBackPressed and use
if to detect the id of activity.
The ItemDetailActivity, in your manifest, doesn't have the parent attribute.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ScheduleActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_agenda"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ItemDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

I've tried NavUtils, startActivity in the OnBackPressed event, but it doens't works.

The code for open the ItemDetail from MapActivity.

```
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener<MyItem>() {
            @Override
            public void onClusterItemInfoWindowClick(MyItem myItem) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, ItemDetailActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("instalattion", myItem.getInstalattion());
                intent.putExtra("activity", "MapActivity");

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
                new RecyclerClickListener(this, new RecyclerClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                     //whatever code

                        Intent intent = new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, ItemDetailActivity.class);

                        intent.putExtra("instalattion", installationTO);
                        intent.putExtra("activity", "ScheduleActivity");

                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }));
    }
```

Comment: Add android:parentActivityName="ACTIVITY_NAME" in your manifest file

Comment: From where do you start ScheduleActivity ?? Please update question with the activity code

Comment: Do you override `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: you might be calling finish() when starting ItemDetailActivity

Comment: Yes, i've tried this before. ScheduleActivity becames the parent activity, ok. But the problem is when I start the ItemDetail by MapActivity, it must back to the MapActivity. Got it? For example: I started the ItemDetail from MapActivity, when I click in the back button, it should back to the MapActivity. Else, back to the ScheduleActivity

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest :

```
  <activity
    android:name=".ItemDetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_item_detail"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <!-- SET YOUR PARENT ACTIVITY -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" android:value=".ScheduleActivity" />
  </activity>
```

So set parent activity of Your ItemDetailActivity to ScheduleActivity and back will go to parent Activity.

Comment: ScheduleActivity becames the parent activity, ok. But the problem is when I start the ItemDetail by MapActivity, it must back to the MapActivity. Got it? For example: I started the ItemDetail from MapActivity, when I click in the back button, it should back to the MapActivity. Else, back to the ScheduleActivity